# Sheet showing available hours between everyone

Tags: google-sheets, spreadsheet, google-sheets-api

I want to create a spreadsheet where I can add people on it and see which hours everyone is available to do a online meeting. It's mandatory to consider the timezone but I have no clue how to do it.

Person1 sheet example: [image: person1 available sheet example]

Matching hours: [image: sheet showing how many matches]

I think my idea of showing 'matches 4 out of 5' is nice, cause the remaining one can make an effort to show up and edit it so it can be like 'matches 5 out of 5'. But any other suggestion is welcome.

The link of the actual spreadsheet(copy to your own drive so you can edit): https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1yun8uMW2LZUumlm6cy3hqPT-FLQipADSIjLQPNiwXl4/edit?usp=sharing

PS: It would be nice to support DST (daylight save time) but it's not mandatory. The person who is in DST will adjust it.

Comment: Would you please edit your question to explain/demonstrate two things: 1) for the "Match" sheet, please explain how you propose to adjust the matches by timezone; 2) everyone is either available all day, or not available all day. Please provide an example where some staff are unavailable during specific hours of the day.

Comment: Made some changes in the spreadsheet to illustrate it better. 1) In the cell D1 every owner of the current sheet will edit with his correspondent timezone based on GMT. 2) No, was only an example. I tried to mix up a little bit so can seems to be more "real".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your timezone values are all offsets of the Match Sheet (if the match sheet says 01:00 and your timezone is -1, your local time would be 00:00), here is some code that will show you the text in the way that you want:

```
function availablePeople(startTime, dayOfWeek) { //All slots are 1 hour long
  const sheetsNames = ["person1", "person2", "person3", "person4"]; //Edit this to update possibilities
  const dayHeaderRow = 2;
  const startTimeCol = 1;
  const endTimeCol = 2;

  var sheets = SpreadsheetApp.getActive();

  var referenceHourRow = sheets.getSheetByName("match").getRange(dayHeaderRow+1, startTimeCol, 24).getValues().map(function (x) {return x.toString()}).indexOf(startTime.toString());

  var referenceDayCol = sheets.getSheetByName(sheetsNames[0]).getRange(dayHeaderRow, endTimeCol+1, 1, 7).getValues()[0].indexOf(dayOfWeek);

  var availablePeople = 0;

  if (referenceHourRow != -1) {
    for (var i = 0; i<sheetsNames.length; i++) {
      var personSheet = sheets.getSheetByName(sheetsNames[i]);
      var timezone = -personSheet.getRange(1, 4).getValue();

      var thisDayCol = referenceDayCol;
      var thisHourRow = referenceHourRow;

      if (timezone!=0) {
        if (thisHourRow+timezone<0) {
          //Went back a day.
          thisDayCol = (thisDayCol+6)%7;
          thisHourRow = 24-(referenceHourRow-timezone);
        } else if (thisHourRow+timezone>=24) {
          //Went forward a day
          thisDayCol = (thisDayCol+1)%7;
          thisHourRow = (thisHourRow+timezone)%24;
        } else {
          thisHourRow += timezone;
        }
      }

      var cell = personSheet.getRange(dayHeaderRow+1+thisHourRow, endTimeCol+1+thisDayCol);

      if (cell.getValue()=="Available") {
        availablePeople++;
      }
    }
  }

  return availablePeople+" out of "+sheetsNames.length;
}
```

This is how to use this function: `=availablePeople(<START TIME>,<DAY OF THE WEEK>)`.

To allow this to be dragged and autocompleted, write `=availablePeople($A3,C$2)` in the "Monday" "00:00" and then drag it horizontally and vertically to update the formula.

Comment: `=availablePeople($A3,C$2)` (i.e. Monday 00:00). Based on the OP's test data, I get "1 out of 3". Do you agree? Which of the 3 people in the OP's data is this?

Comment: I'm testing it out if there is any issue with the function, but what I was thinking is pretty much what ZektorH coded. I've already give a thumbs up for it.

Comment: Hello @Tedinoz, I have inputted my own test data while working on this.
Also, Luís Fernando, remember to accept answers that are helpful to you since this helps Stack Overflow users to find the correct answers.

Comment: Don't worry I will. So I made some tests with everyone with Timezone 0 (to make everything easier to check) and I think the code has an issue: [link](https://imgur.com/OOOGxQN) The only cell on monday that should show '4 out of 4' is the 19:00-20:00 cell combination and it is showing 5 cells with '4 out of 4' which doesn't make any sense I think.

Comment: Hello @LuísFernando, please be aware that Google Sheets won't update cells with formulas which have no changes in the parameters. To force this update, delete the cells with the formulas and undo that action (restore them). Let me know if that fixes it.

Comment: @ZektorH U r right, probably this is the issue. Tyvm. Is there a way to create something to force this update without doing this? Like a "button in a cell"(if this is even possible).

Comment: You can [create a macro](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/7665004?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) or a [trigger](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers) that performs the update on those cells.